# undelete (-W) with rm (BSD General Commands) - Operation not supported

Tags: terminal, command-line, unix, data-recovery, file-recovery

How to enable undelete for files in my `Downloads` folder? How does this `undelete` works?

```
$ rm backupstore.files.tar.gz 
$ rm -W backupstore.files.tar.gz
rm: backupstore.files_.tar.gz: Operation not supported
$ ls -W
AdBlock.safariextz          launch (1).ica              mysql-connector-java-2.0.14.tar.gz      launch.ica              mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.tar.gz
$ rm launch.ica 
$ rm -W launch.ica
rm: launch.ica: Operation not supported
```

Infos about the filesystem

```
$ diskutil info /dev/disk1
   Device Identifier:        disk1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1
   Whole:                    Yes
   Part of Whole:            disk1
   Device / Media Name:      APPLE SSD SM0512G

   Volume Name:              Macintosh HD
   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /

   Content (IOContent):      Apple_HFS
   File System Personality:  Journaled HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                  Journal size 40960 KB at offset 0x11991000
   Owners:                   Enabled

   OS Can Be Installed:      Yes
   Recovery Disk:            disk0s3
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 PCI
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              D27270EB-9784-3B29-A1EE-D26DBC2BD22E
   Disk / Partition UUID:    FC74BE3D-F4EA-4FD1-B362-D651EB68CFA1

   Disk Size:                499.0 GB (499046809600 Bytes) (exactly 974700800 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:       499.0 GB (499046809600 Bytes) (exactly 974700800 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:        104.3 GB (104267853824 Bytes) (exactly 203648152 512-Byte-Units) (20.9%)
   Volume Available Space:   394.8 GB (394778955776 Bytes) (exactly 771052648 512-Byte-Units) (79.1%)
   Allocation Block Size:    4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No

   Device Location:          Internal
   Removable Media:          Fixed

   Solid State:              Yes
   Virtual:                  Yes
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

   This disk is a Core Storage Logical Volume (LV).  Core Storage Information:
   LV UUID:                  FC74BE3D-F4EA-4FD1-B362-D651EB68CFA1
   LVF UUID:                 544B362A-53F4-41FF-B1AD-BE52860C04CA
   LVG UUID:                 C92FBB59-95F2-4E6B-AABA-39267836FCE3
   PV UUID (disk):           6C0409A0-8BBB-4BFC-B422-37782F7EA2B5 (disk0s2)
   Fusion Drive:             No
   Encrypted:                No
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man rm`:

```
 -W    Attempt to undelete the named files.  Currently, this option can only be 
       used to recover files covered by whiteouts.
```

So it can't be used to recover files deleted by the usual means.

For a (rather short) explanation of whiteout see https://askubuntu.com/questions/39826/what-does-whiteout-mean-in-a-copy-on-write-filesystem. A slightly better explanation I found on [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10978441#message10978441):

> A whiteout node is used are part of a union file system mount, where a 2nd file system is mounted over a base file system, and the files in both file systems appear to be merged.
>
> When you delete a file in the union file system which happens to be in the bottom layer (which is effectively read-only), the top layer gets a whiteout node created to indicate that the bottom layer file should not be returned on a directory lookup.
>
> So while I did not find anything about deleting a whiteout node, my theory is that maybe if you create a real file or directory with the exact same name as the whiteout node you created, the file system will automatically remove the whiteout node. Or try renaming a file to the same name as the whiteout node.